# how to call command line through c#

Tags: c#

I have this command line:

`LSPrintingDialog.exe -f "C:\Program Files\LightScribe Template Labeler\templatelabeler\content\templates\backgrounds\GiftTags.jpg" -n "HP dvd de8a4l rh61 211 (J:)" -i 0 -q draft -p J -c 1 -m 1`

With CMD, I am able to call this command line directly, how can I call this command line through C#?

Comment: Note that that command line will only work on your machine; generalizing it to work on other machines will take non-trivial effort.

Answer (score 4):

You need to call `Process.Start(exePath, arguments)` and accept answers to your questions.

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            proc.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = CMD

  CMD ="LSPrintingDialog.exe -f "C:\Program Files\LightScribe Template Labeler\templatelabeler\content\templates\backgrounds\GiftTags.jpg" -n "HP dvd de8a4l rh61 211 (J:)" -i 0 -q draft -p J -c 1 -m 1 
";
            proc.Start();

Comment: @ SlAKS , i have many errors for the command line message, do you have any adv?

Comment: You should call `Process.Start` on your actual command, not `cmd.exe`.